# what version is LuaR

Tags: lua, decompiler

In my file `main.Lua` i have the first line

```
 LuaR   “
```

When i tried to `decompile` it and read the code in `Lua` version `5.3.5` it saids:

```
 Version mismatch in precompiled chunk
```

What version is my `main.lua` file ?. How do i `decompile` it?

I have seen one post like this but its `LuaQ` and not `LuaR` .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

'LuaR' is part of the header of precompiled Lua 5.2 scripts.

The 'R' is actually '0x52' in hex, which codifies the Lua version.